# how to solve this problems with java?

Tags: java

user enter ticket and ticket should be start with B, E, F ( case insensitive ex. b e f also acceptable ) and after that 3 digit..

if they enter proper format of ticket than book ticket
else invalid ticket error.

for example.

> java Ticket
>   Enter ticket >> b100
>   Cost $200.0
>   java Ticket
>   Enter ticket >> A609
>   Invalid ticket, ticket must start with B, F or E
>   java Ticket
>   Enter ticket >> 1234567890987
>   Invalid ticket, wrong length, length must be between 4 and 10
>   inclusive

code is

```
import java.util.*;
public class Ticket
{

    public static void main(String[] ar)throws IOException
    {
        Scanner keb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter ticket := ");
        String ticket=keb.nextLine();



        if( checkTickt)
        {
            System.out.println("valid ticket");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid ticket, ticket must start with B, F or E");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Use regex `[B,F,E,b,f,e][0-9]{3}`

Comment: que. ??  is user enter ticket . but ticket should be start with B,E,F or b, e f.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **regular expression**:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ticket {

    public static void main(String[] ar) throws IOException {
        Scanner keb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter ticket:");
        String ticket = keb.nextLine();
        String pattern = "[BbFfEe][0-9]{3}";


        if (ticket.matches(pattern)) {
            System.out.println("Ticket is VALID.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ticket is INVALID, it must starts with B, b, F, f, E, e characters following by 3 digits.");
        }
    }
}
```

Read more: [Lesson: Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: The "Error" message is not correct.

Comment: @Blobonat Sure, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve is rather this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)[bef]\\d{3}");
if (pattern.matcher(ticket).matches()) {
    System.out.println("valid ticket");
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid ticket, ticket must start with B, F or E");
}
```

Comment: You should add a check for the 3 digits that are supposed to come after the character imo.

Comment: @RexWagenius good catch I missed that part